# is isset($_SESSION['admin']) a dangerous way to grant access?

Tags: php, session, authentication

If (for argument sake) 'admin-access' was granted in php with:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']))  // this session would be set
{ // grant access; }            // after a successful login
else { //redirect ;}
```

Would this be a particularly easy thing to bypass and fake, if you knew what the name of the session is (in this case it is admin)?

In other words, can someone easily fake a $_SESSION, if all a script calls for is the session to be 'set'?

Comment: If you use only the above code, then yup, it is dangerous. Session can be fixed, hijacked.... You need to take this into consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `isset()` is not bad for security. It depends on your logic that how you use it. It will be good if you not only check `isset()` but also its value.

**For Example:**

```
if( isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == true ) { 
  // grant access
} else { 
  //redirect 
}
```

Or something like this:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == '1' ) { 
  // grant access
} else { 
  //redirect 
}
```

Comment: Yes very true. Although, $_SESSION variable cannot be magically set in anywhere else. User cannot effect to your $_SESSION variables by any meanings, unless you code it that way. So in theory isset is enough.

Comment: @raPHPid: Yes you are right but it depends that what are you storing in `$_SESSION['admin']`. May be OP storing `admin` or `superadmin` in `$_SESSION['admin']`

Comment: [Javascript Injection](http://www.patricktalmadge.com/2006/11/28/javascript-injection/) can be used against poorly coded authentications. While I am not absolutely certain that Session variables can be affected by this, isset() absolutely is not enough if that is the case.

Comment: Ah, very true. Thinking of it and thinking about application future, it might be very wise to check the value of the variable. Good point. Although, it came to my mind, that coder probably wants superadmin access those admin functions too. So, another kind of solution is needed to separate admins, perhaps level or something. Actually that would be intresting to know what people use, I normally use USERLEVEL type solutions (if from scratch). I must search stackoverflow...

Comment: @maiorano84: there is no way inject variables to $_SESSION (unless you code it something like `<%php $_SESSION[$_GET['varname']=$_GET['varvalue'];` . There are many other ways to attack (XSS,SQL), or hijack sessions, which has nothing to do with injecting variables. If that (inject variables) would be possible, ALL worlds PHP applications would be in danger.

Comment: @raPHPid Good, just wanted to be sure (knew Cookies were a risk, but never tested against Sessions).

Answer (score 0):

i prefer a more secure way, like this class i used in my old applications :

```
class auth {

    protected $userID;
    protected $password;
    protected $username;
    protected $remember;
    protected $userType;

    public function checkAuth($username,$password,$remember=0) {
        global $db;

        $this->password = sha1($password);
        $this->username = strtolower($username);
        $this->remember = $remember;

        $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`,`username`,`password`,`type` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = :username AND `active` = '1' LIMIT 1");
        $sth->execute(array(
            ':username' => $this->username
        ));
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        $this->userType = $result[0]['type'];

        if (@$result[0]['password'] == $this->password) {
            $this->userID = $result[0]['id'];
            $this->makeLogin();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
            exit;
        }
    }

    private function makeLogin() {
        $securityInformation = $this->username . '|-|' . $this->password . '|-|' . $this->userID . '|-|' . $this->userType;
        $hash = $this->encode($securityInformation);
        if ($this->remember) {
            setcookie('qdata',$hash,time()+604800,'/');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['qdata'] = $hash;
        }
        $this->updateStats();
    }

    public function isLogin() {
        global $db, $ua, $cache;

        $data = $this->getUserInfo();
        if ($data) {

            $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT `password`,`last_login_ip` FROM `user` WHERE `id` = :ID LIMIT 1');
            $sth->execute(array(
                ':ID' => $data['userID']
            ));

            $result = $sth->fetchAll();
            if ( ($result[0]['password'] == $data['password']) AND ($result[0]['last_login_ip'] == $ua->getIP()) ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        if (@isset($_COOKIE['qdata'])) {
            setcookie('qdata','',time()-200, '/');
        } 
        if (@isset($_SESSION['qdata'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['qdata']);
        }
    }

    private function parseHash($hash) {
        $userData = array();
        list($userData['username'],$userData['password'],$userData['userID'],$userData['userType']) = explode('|-|',$this->decode($hash));
        return $userData;
    }

    public function getUserInfo() {
        if (@isset($_COOKIE['qdata'])) {
            $data = $this->parseHash($_COOKIE['qdata']);
            return $data; 
        } elseif (@isset($_SESSION['qdata'])) {
            $data = $this->parseHash($_SESSION['qdata']);
            return $data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function encode($str) {
        $chr = '';
        $prt = '';
        for($i=0;$i < strlen($str);$i++) {
            $prt = (chr(ord(substr($str,$i,1)) + 3)) . chr(ord(substr($str,$i,1)) + 2);
            $chr =  $prt . $chr;
        }
        return str_rot13($chr);
    }

    private function decode($str) {
        $chr = '';
        $prt = '';
        $str = str_rot13($str);
        for($i=0;$i < strlen($str);$i++) {
            if($i % 2 == 0) {
                $prt = (chr(ord(substr($str,$i,1)) - 3));
                $chr = $prt . $chr;
            }
        }
        return $chr;    
    }
}
```

if you dont like this approach, at least store a special key in admin table and use session with that key in value, also check login is validated every time a page loaded.

Comment: This requires the database, whereas the OP's initial solution does not.

Comment: Sorry, I do use a database to initially check for a match in passowrd + username, but this question is more geared towards a separate page simply checking if the username is set, and if that would be secure enough. 
This is a great answer with a lot to learn from, thanks!

I'm very interested to see what other opinions are

Comment: @Tadeck well yea, you are right,  but i wanted to give him some idea about better ways to authenticate users

Comment: @PayamB: Can I ask why do you store user password to cookie? Isn't that decreasing security? Isn't it enough that user authenticates once, and while user is holding authentication cookie, he is 'valid' and authenticated?

Comment: @raPHPid **sha1 hashed password** encoded by encode() function will be stored on cookie, think about you logged in to your account in your work place remembered by cookie,  day after that you changed your password in home, without checking for password your last login on work is still valid, even when you changed your password.

Comment: @payamb: it is a very bad idea to store anything sensitive data in cookies (encoding or not doesn't matter). Even sha1 has its vulnerability against collision attacks. You should never ever store password in cookie.